# jq how to replace a clear text to a text variable

Tags: json

When I use commmand:

```
jq -r '.balances[] | select(.asset=="BTC").free' wallet.json
```

result: "4723846.89208129"

When I use command:

```
coin2=BTC    
jq -r '.balances[] | select(.asset=="$coin2").free' wallet.json
```

result: nothing

How to fix this error? Help me please!

wallet.json here:

```
{
  "makerCommission": 15,
  "takerCommission": 15,
  "buyerCommission": 0,
  "sellerCommission": 0,
  "canTrade": true,
  "canWithdraw": true,
  "canDeposit": true,
  "updateTime": 123456789,
  "accountType": "SPOT",
  "balances": [
    {
      "asset": "BTC",
      "free": "4723846.89208129",
      "locked": "0.00000000"
    },
    {
      "asset": "LTC",
      "free": "4763368.68006011",
      "locked": "0.00000000"
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "SPOT"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have a look at my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75591480/9299798

Answer (score 4):

- **First**, pass that variable value to `jq` with `--arg coin2 "$coin2"` first like so:

  ```
  jq -r --arg coin2 "$coin2" '.balances[] | select(.asset==$coin2).free' wallet.json
  ```
- **Second**, don't quote that passed variable `$coin2` inside the `jq` command string `' ... '` or otherwise it will be read literally as a fixed string instead of being expanded to its value.

From [`man jq`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/jq.1.html):

> **--arg** name value:
>
> This  option  passes a value to the jq program as a predefined
> variable. If you run jq    with --arg foo bar, then $foo is available
> in the program and  has  the  value  "bar".    Note that value will be
> treated as a string, so --arg foo 123 will bind $foo to "123".

Comment: Thankyou! Great!